# Powershell - While Statement

Tags: powershell, while-loop

Does anyone know why this while statement will not return TRUE when I enter "A" or "PTR" into the Read-Host?

```
$lookupDecision = Read-Host "Do you want results for A or PTR: "

while( $lookupDecision -ne "A" -or $lookupDecision -ne "PTR" ) {
    $lookupDecision = Read-Host "Invalid input! Enter A or PTR: "
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement *does* return TRUE, and will do so no matter what you enter. If you enter `A`, it results in TRUE because `A` is not equal to `PTR`. If you enter `PTR` it results in TRUE because it's not equal to `A`. Anything else is not equal to both of them.

The problem here is that you want it eventually return FALSE, so you can move past the while loop to the next section of code. To do this, you need a `-and` instead of a `-or`.

```
$lookupDecision = Read-Host "Do you want results for A or PTR: "

while( $lookupDecision -ne "A" -and $lookupDecision -ne "PTR" ) {
    $lookupDecision = Read-Host "Invalid input! Enter A or PTR: "
}
```

Comment: `[string]::Compare()` is unnecessary here, the default mode of all comparison operators in PowerShell is case-insensitivity when operating on strings. You have to state case-sensitive comparison operations explicitly, ie. `"a" -cne "A"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I was expecting that, but when I tested the first version before posting I just typed "a" and it failed. I had to use A to get it to work, and this fixed it. I think it depends on the version of PowerShell.

Comment: Interesting, what version/platform did you see this behavior with? In any case, the idiomatic powershell solution here is `-ine` rather than `[string]::Compare()`

Comment: Win8.1 PS4.0, which I expect would support that.

Comment: ... and now I can't reproduce the problem :( I'll just delete the 2nd part.

Comment: Yeah, that's really strange. Sounds a bit like a bug to me (I have yet to find a way to change the default behavior in this area). See `Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators` for reference

Answer (score 0):

Do while's are awesome for prompting users for input

```
do {
     $lookupDecision = Read-Host "Do you want results for A or PTR: "
} while ($lookupDecision -ne "A" -And $lookupDecision -ne "PTR")
```

Comment: This still has the bad `-or` and won't work. Also, it can confuse users if the prompt never changes. Better to have something to indicate the problem.